# Rigorous proof that $\int_{\Omega}X\;dP=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x)\;dx$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, expected-value, faq

I'm trying to prove rigorously that $\int_{\Omega}X\;dP=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x)\;dx$.  Where $f$ is the pdf of the random variable $X$.

I can't find a proof on the wikipedia article, or if it's there then it's disguised enough that I can't recognize it.  Basically what I've got is a sort of semi-rigorous (and probably incorrect) proof of the equality, but maybe somebody could help me flesh out the details.

**Proof:**

Beginning from the definition that $E[X]:=\int_{\Omega}X\;dP$.

Given a random variable $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, we have the induced measure on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ given by $P(\{X\in A\})$.  Then by the Radon-Nikodym theorem there exists a measurable function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ such that $$P(\{X\in A\}) = \int_Afd\mu,$$

where $d\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure.  From here it gets a bit hand-wavy.  Basically since this measure was induced by the random variable $X$, then on $\mathbb{R}$ this random variable is simply given by the identity function $g(x)=x$.  And thus by definition we write the expected value of $g$ with respect to our Radon-Nikodym produced measure in the form $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\;d\Big(\int_Afd\mu\Big).$$

Now by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, this becomes $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x)\;dx.$$

What does everyone think about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll try to provide a little more general result. Let $(\Omega,\ \mathcal{E},\ P)$ be a probability space and let $X\colon \Omega\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a random variable, i.e for each $I\in \mathcal{B}$, $X^{-1}(I)\in\mathcal{E}$, where $\mathcal{B}$ is the usual Borel $\sigma-$algebra on $\mathbb{R}$. Let us write $\mu:=\mu_{X}$ for the probability distribution of $X$, i.e for the measure defined on $\mathcal{B}$ by $\mu(I):=P(X^{-1}(I))$ for each $I\in\mathcal{B}$. Then the following holds.

> **Theorem (Abstract-Concrete Formula):** Let $\phi\colon\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a borelian function, i.e $\phi^{-1}(I)\in\mathcal{B}$ for every $I\in\mathcal{B}$, and write $\phi(X)$ for the composition $\phi\circ X$. Suppose at least one between the integrals $$\int_{\Omega} \phi(X)\ dP\quad\text{and}\quad \int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi (x) \ d\mu $$
>   exists (resp. exists and it is finite). Then also the other one exists (resp. exists and it is finite) and it holds that $$\int_{\Omega} \phi(X)\ dP=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi (x) \ d\mu\ .$$
>   In particular, $\phi(X)$ is summable with respect to $P$ if and only if $\phi$ is summable with respect to $\mu$.

(When I say that a Lebesgue integral for a measurable function exists, I allow that it is not finite). The proof of this fact is quite straightforward but it requires some measure theory results such as the [approximation theorem with simple functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_function) and the [Lebesgue's monotone convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence#Lebesgue.27s_monotone_convergence_theorem). Indeed, suppose first that $\phi$ is a (finitely) simple and positive function. Then also $\phi(X)$ is simple (and positive) and (therefore) both mentioned integrals always exist. Writing $\phi=\sum_{i=1}^{n} c_{i}1_{E_{i}}$, where $n=\vert \phi(\mathbb{R})\vert$, $\phi (\mathbb{R})=\{c_{1},\cdots,c_{n}\}$ and $E_{i}:=\phi^{-1}(\{c_{i}\})$, we get $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi (x) \ d\mu=\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_{i}\mu (E_{i})=\sum_{i} c_{i}P(X^{-1}(E_{i}))=\sum_{i} c_{i}P(X^{-1}(\phi^{-1}(\{c_{i}\})))=\int_{\Omega} \phi(X)\ dP.$$ Assume now $\phi$ is a non-negative borelian function. Then there exists a non-decreasing sequence $(\phi_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ of simple, positive functions such that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\phi_{n}(x)=\phi (x)$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$. By monotone convergence theorem we get immediately that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi (x) \ d\mu=\int_{\mathbb{R}}(\lim_{n\to\infty}\phi_{n} (x)) \ d\mu =\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi_{n} (x) \ d\mu=\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{\Omega}\phi_{n} (X) \ dP=\int_{\Omega} \phi(X)\ dP.$$ Finally, suppose only $\phi\colon \mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a borelian function, with no further restrictions. Then one can write $\phi=\phi^{+}-\phi^{-}$ ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_and_negative_parts) for notation). Suppose $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi (x) \ d\mu$ exists: then at least one between $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi^{+} (x) \ d\mu$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi^{-}(x) \ d\mu$ (say, the first one) must be finite and hence also $\int_{\Omega}(\phi(X))^{+} \ dP$ is finite, i.e $\int_{\Omega}\phi(X)\ dP$ exists. It is now clear that we can conclude with our thesis.

> **Corollary:** In the previous situation, if $E[X]<+\infty$, then $$E[X]:=\int_{\Omega} X\ dP=\int_{\mathbb{R}} x\ d\mu.$$ In particular, if $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue's Measure (on $\mathbb{R}$) and has density $f$, then we get $E[X]=\int_{\mathbb{R}} xf(x)\ dx$ (by (a straightforward consequence of) [Radon-Nikodym theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem)).

Comment: It took me a while to fully digest this but I now see that it is exactly the answer I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: "Let $\phi: \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be a borelian function […]" Doesn't "borelian" mean Arctic? As in [aurora borealis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aurora_borealis)?

Comment: @kahen Quite a deep comment, I'd say...However, one talks about borelian sets, so I don't see why you can't just use the same attribute for a function: borelian $\leftrightarrow$ Borel measurable. Besides this, I might also call it *ice-cream* function if I define what such a function is: in mathematics, at least, it is not so true that *nomina nuda tenemus*.

Comment: @MarcoVergura in English mathematical parlance one speaks of "Borel functions" and "Borel sets". Names of mathematicians are very commonly used as adjectives.

Comment: @kahen Well, ok, but I'd say the question is at least quite controversial, since we speak of *Euclidean* and *Riemannian* geometry, *Boolean* algebra, *Noetherian* and *Artinian* ring, *Cartesian* product and so on and so forth... One is legitimate to get a little bit confused, I'd say!

Comment: @kahen MarcoVergura Riemannian integral? :P

Answer (score 9):

If $X\geqslant0$ almost surely, Fubini yields
$$
E[X]=\int_\Omega X\mathrm dP=\int_\Omega\int_0^\infty\mathbf 1_{t\leqslant X}\mathrm dt\mathrm dP=\int_0^\infty\int_\Omega\mathbf 1_{t\leqslant X}\mathrm dP\mathrm dt=\int_0^\infty P[X\geqslant t]\mathrm dt.
$$
Now, for each $t$,
$$
P[X\geqslant t]=\int_0^\infty \mathbf 1_{x\geqslant t}f(x)\mathrm dx,
$$
hence Fubini again yields
$$
E[X]=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty \mathbf 1_{x\geqslant t}f(x)\mathrm dx\mathrm dt=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty \mathbf 1_{x\geqslant t}\mathrm dtf(x)\mathrm dx=\int_0^\infty xf(x)\mathrm dx.
$$
If $X$ is real valued with $P[X\gt0]\cdot P[X\lt0]\ne0$, use the identity $E[X]=aE[Y]-bE[Z]$ where $a=P[X\gt0]$, $b=P[X\lt0]$, $Y$ has the distribution of $X$ conditioned on $X\gt0$ and $Z$ has the distribution of $-X$ conditioned on $X\lt0$, that is, $a=1-F(0)$, $b=F(0)$,
$$
f_Y(y)=\frac{f(y)}{a}\mathbf 1_{y\gt0},\qquad f_Z(z)=\frac{f(-z)}{b}\mathbf 1_{z\gt0}.
$$
This yields
$$
E[X]=a\int_0^\infty y\frac{f(y)}{a}\mathrm dy-b\int_0^\infty z\frac{f(-z)}{b}\mathrm dz=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}xf(x)\mathrm dx.
$$

Comment: could you explain what $\int_0^{\infty}1_{t\leq X}dt$ means?

Comment: The random variable $U=\mathbf 1_{t\leqslant X}$ is defined by $U(\omega)=1$ if $t\leqslant X(\omega)$ and $U(\omega)=0$ otherwise.

Comment: but what does it mean when you're integrating with respect to $t$?  I can't figure out how that equals $X$

Comment: For every $s\geqslant0$, $\int\limits_0^\infty\mathbf 1_{t\leqslant s}\mathrm dt=\int\limits_0^s\mathrm dt=s$. This applies to $s$ a real number and, pointwisely, to $s$ random.

Comment: oh ok I see, thanks

Comment: @Thoth Why didn't you choose this as answer?

Answer (score 0):

For non-negative $X$, argue as in @Did's proof the well-known result $E[X]=\int_0^\infty P[X\ge t]\,dt$. For general integrable $X$ we have by definition $E[X]=E[X^+]-E[X^-]$. Since $X^+$ is non-negative, its expectation equals
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty P[X^+\ge t]\,dt&=\int_0^\infty P[X\ge t]\,dt\\
&=\int_{t=0}^\infty\int_{x=0}^\infty I[x\ge t]f(x)\,dx\,dt\stackrel{\rm Fubini}=\int_{x=0}^\infty\underbrace{\int_{t=0}^\infty I[t\le x]dt}_x\, f(x)dx
\end{align}
$$
and similarly the expectation of $X^-$ equals
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty P[X^-\ge t]\,dt&=\int_0^\infty P[X\le -t]\,dt\\
&=\int_{t=0}^\infty\int_{x=-\infty}^0 I[x\le -t]f(x)\,dx\,dt
\stackrel{\rm Fubini}=\int_{x=-\infty}^0\underbrace{\int_{t=0}^\infty I[t\le -x]dt}_{-x}\, f(x)dx.
\end{align}
$$
Adding these together gives $E[X]=\int_{-\infty}^0 xf(x)dx +\int_0^\infty xf(x)dx$.