# Expectation of a non-negative random variable

Tags: probability, expected-value

Let $X$ be a real non-negative random variable on the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$. Given that 
$$
E[X]=\int_\Omega \int_0^\infty \chi_{t<X}\,dt\,d\mathbb{P}=\int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}[ X\geq t]\,dt,
$$
show that, for all $\epsilon>0$
$$
E[X]\leq \sum_{n=0}^\infty \epsilon\mathbb{P}[X\geq n\epsilon]\leq E[X]+\epsilon.
$$
Tried to use some Fubini combined with rewriting stuff as countable sums (like $\mathbb{P}[X\geq t]=\mathbb{P}\left[\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{X\geq nt\}\right]$) but I am a bit lost. Some intuition is also highly appreciated (I think I am beaten by the misunderstanding of notation).

Comment: This comment is to link this post as one of the [(abstract) duplicates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29382/356647) to the current choice of [mother post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172841). Also see a [measure-theoretic treatment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402640).

Answer (score 3):

Notice that the summation in the middle is the Riemann sum of the *decreasing* function $f(t) = P(X>t).$ The monotonicity makes it easy to estimate the difference between the sum and the integral. Now, the question is: is the function Riemann integrable, and if not, does it matter?

Comment: I would say that we do not know whether the probability measure of $X$ is Riemann integrable (is this what you are talking about?). However calling it a Riemann sum isn't a stronger assumption given that the trick can be done within the Lebesgue integration (doesn't it?).

Comment: @Ton It is actually NOT the probability measure, but the CDF. Part of the point is that this is a monotonic function and therefore IS Riemann-integrable, so...