# Why is $1_{\{\omega : X(\omega) \geqslant t\}}(\omega) = 1_{\{t: t\leqslant X(\omega)\}}(t)$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measurable-functions

I cannot see the logic behind how $1_{\{\omega : X(\omega) \geqslant t\}}(\omega) = 1_{\{t: t\leqslant X(\omega)\}}(t)$ in the proof here, [Expectation of $\mathbb{E}(X^{k+1})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1302774/expectation-of-mathbbexk1)

Could someone please explain this in more detail.

Comment: Both sides are equal to $1$ if $X(\omega)\ge t$, and to $0$ else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both $1_{\{\omega : X(\omega) \geqslant t\}}(\omega)$ and $1_{\{t: t\leqslant X(\omega)\}}(t)$ are $1$ when $X(\omega) \geqslant t$ and $0$ otherwise.  The only difference between the two expressions is that on the left you think of this as a function of $\omega$ and on the right you think of it as a function of $t$.