# Showing $\mathbb{E}(X^p)=p\int_{0}^{\infty} (1-F_X(u))u^{p-1} \ du$

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, proof-verification

> Let $X$ be a positive continuous random variable with density function $f_X$ and cumulative distribution function $F_X$.
>   By interchanging the double integral, show that for $p\in\mathbb{N}^+$ 
>   $$\mathbb{E}(X^p)=\int_{0}^{\infty} x^pf_X(x) \ dx=p\int_{0}^{\infty} (1-F_X(u))u^{p-1} \ du$$ where $x^p=\int_{0}^{x} pu^{p-1} \ du$.

My solution:

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(X^p)&=\int_{0}^{\infty} x^pf_X(x) \ dx \\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty} \left(\int_{0}^{x} pu^{p-1} \ du\right)f_X(x) \ dx \\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty} f_X(x) \ dx \left(\int_{0}^{x} pu^{p-1}\ du\right) \ \\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty} pu^{p-1}\ du \left(\int_{u}^{\infty} f_X(x) \ dx\right) \ \ \ \ \ \text{(changing from u-simple to x-simple)} \ \\
&=p\int_{0}^{\infty} \left(1-F_X(u)\right)u^{p-1}\ du
\end{align}

I am not so confident that the logic in my answer is correct, especially when I switch the order of integration. Is my working from the third to the forth line correct?

Comment: Your argument is correct. In fact there is a similar formula for any random variable, with or without density.

Comment: Yes, the derivation is correct, In general $$\mathbb{E}(g(X))=\int_{-\infty}^0 g'(u)F_X(u)du+\int_0^{\infty}g'(u)(1-F_X(u))du$$ The derivation for $-\infty$ to $0$ is similar to what you have done with a small change in limits giving the different result.

Comment: Thank you for that!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Any example where i can use this result ? I want to use it .

Comment: Just adding linking this to the [node](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172841) of this network of related posts. See the [meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29382/356647) [post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1868) and the [measure-theoretic treatment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402640).